# Firebase Query Returning Null

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This function has a query that is supposed to get the first 5 values in my database. It uses the lastPostKey to get the next 5 following the retrieval of the first 5.

```
 static func showEvent(pageSize: UInt, lastPostKey: String? = nil,completion: @escaping ([Event]) -> Void) {
        //getting firebase root directory
        var currentEvents = [Event]()
        let eventsByLocationRef = Database.database().reference().child("eventsbylocation").child(User.current.location!)

        //let ref = Database.database().reference().child("events")
        var query = eventsByLocationRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: pageSize)
```

For some reason the query inside this if statement returns null when it is time to grab the next 5. I personally don't see what is wrong with it I even beleieve im using the right method but it returns null no matter what.

```
if let lastPostKey = lastPostKey {
                query = query.queryEnding(atValue: lastPostKey)
            }
            query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print(snapshot)
                print(snapshot.value)
                guard let allObjects = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else{
                    return
                }

                allObjects.forEach({ (snapshot) in
                  print(snapshot.value)
                    EventService.show(forEventKey: snapshot.value as! String, completion: { (event) in
                        currentEvents.append(.init(currentEventKey: snapshot.value as! String, dictionary: (event?.eventDictionary)!))
                      //  print(currentEvents)
                        print(currentEvents.count)
                        completion(currentEvents)
                    })

                })


            })

        }
```

If anyone else can take a look at it and fix it I would greatly appreciate it.Below is a picture of my database where the query is taking place.

```
  "events" : {
    "CCDS" : {
      "attend:count" : 2,
      "event:city" : "San Francisco",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "08/09/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "08/09/2017",
        "start:time" : "5:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Happy hour is more joyful in the summer thanks to Center City District Sips, which offers discounted drinks and appetizers every Wednesday evening.  Catch up with old friends and make a few new ones as Center City’s best bars and restaurants host the summer’s happiest hour every Wednesday from 5-7 p.m.  Enjoy $5 cocktails, $4 wine, $3 beers and half-price appetizers at dozens and dozens of bars and restaurants.",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2FCCDS-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=bcce3968-1cca-4890-a3d0-d8064bd0d1da",
      "event:name" : "center city district sips",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=9b4b9d4f-2d6d-4762-a5fd-c72edb943ac4",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "660 Chestnut St",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    },
    "DD" : {
      "attend:count" : 2,
      "event:city" : "New York",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "08/26/2017",
        "end:time" : "5:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "08/26/2017",
        "start:time" : "1:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Help us celebrate the hard work and creativity of the students and demo the iOS apps and games they've built in only 8 weeks! Developers, entrepreneurs, friends, and industry professionals are all welcome to attend",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2Fmakeschooldemo-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=1e75d18d-1949-48e8-a208-2ca88cde395b",
      "event:name" : "demo day",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FDD%2FDemo%20Night%202017%20-%20Make%20School%20Product%20College.mp4?alt=media&token=d9adb4b1-5689-4b15-96b2-e18138701526",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "394 Broadway",
      "event:zip" : 10013
    },
    "MIA" : {
      "attend:count" : 23,
      "event:city" : "San Francisco",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
        "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles.Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM.",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2FMadeInAmerica-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=1ac6e794-6a1f-4f8a-bdb0-afc91f8ba6ae",
      "event:name" : "made in america",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=9b4b9d4f-2d6d-4762-a5fd-c72edb943ac4",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    },
    "MIA2" : {
      "attend:count" : 2,
      "event:city" : "Philadelphia",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
        "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles. Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM. This is different regardless of the same name in database",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2Fmadeinamerica2.jpg?alt=media&token=bd5eb5e4-4e22-4412-a34b-2dc6c9ae561e",
      "event:name" : "made in america",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=9b4b9d4f-2d6d-4762-a5fd-c72edb943ac4",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    },
    "MIA3" : {
      "attend:count" : 8,
      "event:city" : "Philadelphia",
      "event:date" : {
        "end:date" : "09/03/2017",
        "end:time" : "7:00 PM",
        "start:date" : "09/02/2017",
        "start:time" : "12:00 PM"
      },
      "event:description" : "Budweiser Made in America Festival is an annual music festival held in Philadelphia and formerly simultaneously held in Los Angeles. Sponsored by Anheuser–Busch and produced by Live Nation, the event features several stages that continuously host live music from a wide range of genres including hip hop, rock, pop, R&B, and EDM.",
      "event:imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_flyers%2Fmadeinamerica3-compressor.jpg?alt=media&token=9166e2fb-ac9d-46d5-b06f-60cffc337b15",
      "event:name" : "made in america",
      "event:promo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventful-3d558.appspot.com/o/event_promo_vid%2FMIA%2FBudweiser%20Made%20In%20America%20Festival%202013%20August%2031%20-%20September%201.mp4?alt=media&token=9b4b9d4f-2d6d-4762-a5fd-c72edb943ac4",
      "event:state" : "PA",
      "event:street:address" : "Ben Franklin Parkway",
      "event:zip" : 19130
    }
  },
  "eventsbylocation" : {
    "37%2e7,-122%2e4" : {
      "event0" : "MIA",
      "event1" : "CCDS",
      "event2" : "MIA2",
      "event3" : "MIA3",
      "event4" : "CCDS",
      "event5" : "MIA",
      "event6" : "MIA2",
      "event7" : "MIA3",
      "event8" : "CCDS",
      "event9" : "MIA"
    },
    "40%2e7,-74%2e0" : {
      "event" : "DD"
    }
  },
```

Comment: add print(lastPostKey) at the start of if and see what it contains

Comment: it contains the second to last post key

Comment: @3stud1ant3 see comments

Comment: Sorry I can not understand, it prints second?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 it does not prnt the last one it prints the one right before that

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen help please